# Discontinuities of function from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

After reading this page from Rudin I have some question:

1) Why Rudin defines $f$ on $(a,b)$? Why not $[a,b]$ or $[a,b)$?

2) Let $\text{Dom}(f)=E\subset X$ where $X$ is a metric space and $p\in E$ is a limit point of $E$. $f$ is continuous at $p$ *if and only if* $f(p+)=f(p-)=f(p).$ Am I true?

I thought that last condition can be replaced by $f(p+)=f(p-)\neq f(p)$. But if $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^1-\{0\}$ and we got contadiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, the emphasis of Rudin's definition is that for a one-sided limit of $f$ to exist at a point, it is not necessary for $f$ to be defined at that point. If you read carefully, $f$ is not defined at $a$ but we can talk about the one-sided limit $f(a+)$ of $f$ at $a$. It does no harm to define $f$ on $[a,b]$ though, just lose the emphasis.

For question 2, negative. In many metric spaces $X$, you cannot carry on the concepts of "left" and "right" on the real line to the metric space $X$, which may not even be a continuum. Even if we have the concepts of "left" and "right", say $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, there are far more directions to choose to attain a limit point. $f$ is said to be continuous at, say, $0$ if for any sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $0$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(0)$. There you have to take care of far more than the "one-sided limits", say $x_n = (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ or $x_n = (0,-\frac{1}{n^2})$.

Comment: I think that $2)$ is true when $X=\mathbb{R}^1$. Right?

Comment: The "if-and-only-if" condition is true and your counter-example against the original thought is also good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and clear answer to my questions.